# Map only displays tiles

Tags: android, google-maps

I've read many problems like this and also tried the solution but it still display grey tiles, I checked the manifest and looks ok. I am testing it on my device.
Here is my manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dr.droid.lee"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drdroid"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name = "com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".FirstAid" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Health" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DrugGuide" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Symptom" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FResult" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HospResult" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my xml of the mapview with API Key.

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mv1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvCity"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:apiKey="my_api_key"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the key that you are using to build the application doesn't match the key you used to generate the google maps api key.

Double check the default keystore configuration.

If you are using Eclipse + ADT go to:

> Window > Preferences > Android > Build > Default debug keystore

Comment: i did that process custom debug keystore is blank. what should i do? default debug keystore has a valid path

Comment: You should point that configuration to the keystore file you used to generate the google maps api key.

Comment: it now looks like this: Default debug key store : C:\Users\Lee\.android\debug.keystore  Custom debug key store: C:\Users\Lee\.android\debug.keystore. is this right?

Comment: Is right as long as that's the keystore you used to generate the maps api key. Give it a try, if it works is because you generated the api key with that keystore, otherwise you are still missing the right keystore file

Comment: still doesnt work, i havent tried using it in the emulator., when i try to create a virtual device using google api it states the it has missing kernel file

Comment: Use that keystore you found and generate a new google maps api key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Comment: it still gives me the same api key

Comment: Are you sure you are configuring the right mapview? that your device has an active internet connection? did you clean and re build your app after setting the new keystore?

Comment: Its working fine now, i didnt notice that i was using jre7 so it was generating SHA1 by default instead of MD5. Thanks for your time sir!

Answer (score 0):

The API Key for "debug" ONLY works on emulators. 
If you use Eclise to load the software in "debug mode" to a handset, you will get tiles, not a map. 
If you update the mapview with a "release" API key, then use Eclipse "EXPORT" to create an apk file, copy this to the sd card on the handset, then use an installer app (download free from Google Play) to install it on the phone!!!